# How did Asian Americans manage to become richer than an average American?

Tags: united-states, economy, social-history, asia, labour-history

By "richer" I mean higher median income.

Large-scale immigration of Asians to the United States began in the 19th century. In the beginning, most of them were poorer than an average American. Nevertheless, in the subsequent century, the income of Asian Americans was gradually increasing. Nowadays, they have higher median income than an average American.

Personal and Household income in the United States in 2005:
[image: Personal and Household income in the United States in 2005]

How did they achieve this even though they originally came from countries much poorer than the United States?

Comment: There are many factors (e.g. emphasis on higher education), but note that immigrating from a poor country doesn't necessarily mean the immigrants themselves were poor. Many wealthy Chinese families escaped to the United States ahead of the Communist takeover, for example. And while certainly not always the case, often it is skilled labour/other entrepreneurial individuals who migrate.

Comment: There's also considerable and persistent differences within the category "Asian American." Different ethnic groups (e.g. Japanese, Vietnamese) have different median incomes, different immigration histories, and different reasons for being in the United States. So it's not always clear why "Asian Americans" is the relevant unit of analysis.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable calling this history.  Social science or economics perhaps, but history?

Comment: If you look at the data, the difference is only appreciable at the "household" level. More women working? Asian young men and women leaving home later? That would imply that in average, those households will have a greater income only because they are more individuals working.

Comment: Also, you should really point your sources. Because at it stands, you could have taken the graph from a white supremacy group page (which usually are not know for presenting data in a neutral, unbiased way).

Comment: Concur with @SJuan76; use of the graphic without attribution is also potentially an infringement of copyright, and a bit of an insult to the person or institution that took the effort to compile the statistics.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with the implict collective stereotype of "Asian Americans"; I'm uncomfortable with trying to find a simple explanation for a phenomena that I suspect is complex and subtle; I suspect that any answer we can give will be misleadingly terse.  I'm not confident that this phenomena can be analyzed through a historical analytical techniques; I suspect this is a question that more properly belongs in sociology or perhaps economics.

Comment: Educated guess: I was thinking that probably Asian-Americans are more concentrated in the biggest cities (at least that's what I know from seing Hollywood movies). These cities usually offer higher salaries from the same jobs (but also higher cost of living) than small cities and towns, and could be enough to explain the differences in individual incoming. Of course, no data to back it up, so I am not willing to put that as an answer. Can someone provide data for an answer for that guess? (or, at the opposite, point to some flaw or contrary data).

Answer (score 9):

There is no good answer to this question as posed, because many Asian-American ethnicities are poorer than the U.S. general public. In fact, Asian Americans' high incomes are largely due to **Indian Americans,** which is not necessarily the group most Americans think of when they hear the term "Asian American."

Let's look at a 2012 Pew study of "[The Rise of Asian Americans](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2012/06/19/the-rise-of-asian-americans/):"

> The Pew Research Center survey was designed to contain a nationally
>   representative sample of each of the six largest Asian-American groups
>   by country of origin—Chinese Americans, Filipino Americans, Indian
>   Americans, Vietnamese Americans, Korean Americans and Japanese
>   Americans. Together these groups comprise at least 83% of the total
>   Asian population in the U.S.
>
> The basic demographics of these groups are different on many measures.
>   For example, **Indian Americans lead all other groups by a significant
>   margin in their levels of income and education.** Seven-in-ten
>   Indian-American adults ages 25 and older have a college degree,
>   compared with about half of Americans of Korean, Chinese, Filipino and
>   Japanese ancestry, and about a quarter of Vietnamese Americans.
>
> On the other side of the socio-economic ledger, **Americans with Korean,
>   Vietnamese, Chinese and “other U.S. Asian” origins have higher shares
>   in poverty than does the U.S. general public**, while those with Indian,
>   Japanese and Filipino origins have lower shares.

So three "Asian American" groups are more likely to be impoverished than the average American and three "Asian American" groups are not. Vietnamese Americans and "other Asian American" groups earn around $5,000/year less than the average American ($40,000/year); the average Filipino American earns about as much as the average American; the average Korean American earns $5,000 more, the average Chinese American earns $10,000 more, while Japanese Americans on average earn $15,000 more and Indian Americans about $25,000 more. Furthermore, these groups all differ from one another on plenty of other important cultural dimensions. **So there is no reasonable answer to this question as posed.** One would need to ask about the histories of these groups separately.

Source: [Full Pew Report, 2013](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/files/2013/04/Asian-Americans-new-full-report-04-2013.pdf)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Korean- Vietnamese- and Chinese- Americans are not poorer "on average" than other Americans. (Maybe the Vietnamese.) They do have higher poverty rates because their wealth distributions are more skewed. More "low end" members of these groups are balanced by more high end members. The Filipinos are the opposite: less extremes of wealth and poverty, but they're no better off "on average" than other Asians,

Comment: @TomAu: Thanks, good point. I edited based on your comments and added a link to the full report